# Sharing objects with all verticles instances

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

My application, an API server, is thought to be organized as follows:

1. `MainVerticle` is called on startup and should create all necessary objects for the application to work. Mainly a mongoDB pool of connections (`MongoClient.createShared(...)`) and a global configuration object available instance-wide. It also starts the HTTP Listener, several instances of a `HttpVerticle`.
2. `HttpVerticle` is in charge of receiving requests and, based the command `xxx` in the payload, execute the `XxxHandler.handle(...)` method.
3. Most of the `XxxHandler.handle(...)` methods will need to access the database. In addition, some others  will also deploy additional verticles with parameters from the global conf. For example `LoginHandler.handle(...)` will deploy a verticle to keep user state while he's connected and this verticle will be undeployed when the user logs out.

I can't figure out how to get the global configuration object while being in `XxxHandler.handle(...)` or in a "sub"-verticle. Same for the mongo client.

**Q1**: For configuration data, I tried to use `SharedData`. In `MainVerticle.start() I have:

```
LocalMap<String, String> lm = vertx.sharedData().getLocalMap("conf");
lm.put("var", "val");
```

and in `HttpVerticle.start() I have:

```
LocalMap<String, String> lm = vertx.sharedData().getLocalMap("conf");
log.debug("var={}", lm.get("var"));
```

but the log output is `var=null`.... What am I doing wrong ?

**Q2**: Besides this basic example with a `<String, String>` map type, what if the value is a mutable Object like `JsonObject` which actually is what I would need ?

**Q3**: Finally how to make the instance of the mongo client available to all verticles?

Comment: LocalMap is the way to share objects between verticles in the same Vert.x instance. These objects should be immutable (but JsonObject will be copied). Not sure what doesn't work for you without more snippets.

Comment: As for Mongo, if all your verticles use `createShared` with the same pool name, they will all use the same pool (created just once).

Comment: My `var` had become `vqr` and I spent a couple of hours trying to figure out what was going on... And thanks for the advice on MongoClient.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getLocalMap()` you should be using `getClusterWideMap()`. Then you should be able to operate on shared data accross the whole cluster and not just in one verticle.

Be aware that the shared operations are async and the code might look like (code in Groovy):

```
vertx.sharedData().getClusterWideMap( 'your-name' ){ AsyncResult<AsyncMap<String,String>> res ->
  if( res.succeeded() )
    res.result().put( 'var', 'val', { log.info "put succeeded: ${it.succeeded()}" } )
}
```

You should be able to use any `Serializable` objects in your map.

Comment: I don't really know what I did wrong (misspelling ?) but I actually rewrote the same lines and the `LocalMap` works fine across all verticles running in the same `vertx` instance. I actually don't want to have this data shared across the cluster: its  configurations which may not be the sames on different nodes.